# How can I get the Windows 7 calculator on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, calculator

Can anyone please let me know is it possible to install Windows 7 calculator on Windows XP?
If so what is the procedure to install it and 
could you please send me the link of the Windows 7 calculator that supports Windows XP?

Comment: Try copying `c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe` from a Windows 7 machine to a Windows XP machine and see if it runs?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - it doesn't. Calc.exe returns an error message

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the easiest answer to a Microsoft question is actually Microsoft themselves.
Within their Download Free Tools Section you will find something which is called
["Microsoft Calculator Plus"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=21622).
It has been available for at least 8 years. I have used it for a long time in XP and Vista.
Amazingly albeit MS had it available they never integrated it into their OS installation Disks for Windows XP SR3 or any of the Vista Versions, neither was it integrated into any of their Service Release Updates.
Strange, I have no idea why since it looks the same but includes mathematical and conversion functions.
The only issue with it is that it installs with an odd looking interface. But you can change it to the classic style in the menu. What a relief.

> [image]
>
> [Additional Picutres](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=microsoft%20calculator%20plus&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=3zEyUdv6M8ab1AW874CAAg&ved=0CEEQsAQ&biw=1680&bih=913).

Comment: Yeah, the default theme freaked me out, I've never seen anything that ugly before! @gsgoodguy: The classic theme looks exactly like the calc.exe you're used to from XP.

Answer (score 1):

It probably isn't possible, certainly isn't supported and may well be in violation of the license agreement for Windows (although you may want to have that reviewed by a lawyer to be sure). Copying the binary might work, but it is unlikely since the calculator is part of windows so they have no need to make it run on downlevel versions.

Running the W7 version of calc in XP will get you an error of "not a valid win32 application", compatibility mode will not help.

Comment: re that error you mention, what if the w7 is w7 32bit?  maybe you'd get that error you mention even if you tried calc.exe of w7 64bit on w732bit.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](http://www.geeksdesk.com/windows-7-calculator-for-windows-xp-sp2/)

As you all know there are lots of user who have already introduced Windows 7 calculator for XP, but using Windows 7 calculator in XP requires Microsoft.Net Framework. Here I am Re-introducing a new version of Windows 7 calculator for XP which don’t required any Microsoft.Net Framework.

This calculator Mod has been developed by Mr. Harsh Shivhare. You can install or use it in Windows XP SP2 – SP3, either replace Calc.exe in System32 folder or just click on calc.exe to run it.

You can download it from following link:

[Download Windows 7 Calculator for XP SP2](http://www.ziddu.com/download/12862693/Calc.rar.html)

[Virus report-Clean](http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=ad3631232d95633cd3b21cf2c46709586e29808dd6ea24c93ceeac8a5a3a93c1-1302193374)

---

Or you could:

And for Windows XP’s users, you too can have the Windows 7 Calculator on your machine. This XP version of Windows 7 Calculator has the similar interface as the original one but it can only work for standard mode. It is very sad that you can’t try the two newly added modes, Programmer and Statistics. Installation is not needed to use this calculator. Just extract the downloaded zip file and run the calc.exe file. You need Microsoft .NET framework 3.5 on your Windows in order to run the application.

[Download Windows 7 Calculator for Windows XP Now](http://grdcityboy.deviantart.com/art/Seven-Calculator-102484514)

[Virus report-clean](http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=7a34b8c8bab68c6949cbb0cb5444a2236587e33caa38a9eaafe54f38f73b5c60-1302193589)

---

Alternatively in Vista:

Download [Windows-7-Calculator.rar](http://www.ziddu.com/download/2612928/Windows-7-Calculator.rar.html).

[Virus report-clean-1hit](http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=90377a2dee45dcef0af034faf6ce5edf2c51b737774ae8eab21e5a3fa49e0592-1302193324)

Unpack the content to another folder, and run the calc.exe to use the Windows 7 Calculator in Windows Vista. 
To replace existing default Calculator program in Windows Vista, copy calc.exe to \Windows\System32\, and calc.exe.mui (in en-US folder) to \Windows\System32\en-US\ folder, overwriting existing file (you may want to backup the old Calculator binaries first in case of error running Windows 7 version). Voila, now the new Windows 7 Calculator has been installed on Windows Vista.

Comment: Neither of these let you run Windows 7's calculator on an XP machine, as OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

Calculator Plus was already mentioned above, but Microsoft also offers another advanced calculator for download on their site which has more functions and graphing calculator abilities: [Microsoft Mathematics 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15702)

Answer (score -1):

Here on this website it tells you:

http://www.trishtech.com/2016/01/how-to-run-windows-8-1-calculator-in-windows-10/

If you do not want to go to it, you just copy the one in

```
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
```

and

```
C:\Windows\System32\en-US\Calc.exe.mui
```

Make sure you create a folder title

```
en-US
```

and put the

```
Calc.exe.mui
```

in it.

By the way I got it from Windows 8.1 and tested it on Windows 10.

Comment: Question is how to use Windows 7's calculator on xp. your post doesn't answer it.